# Why do both friend functions and get and set functions have access to class members?

Tags: c++

I have a question. I am writing an employee management program. The program can search for employee information, add or edit information, etc.. I write my program using OOP, but I'm confused by being able to easily access and modify variables in class by using get and set method in main function and global function instead of declaring friend function. So I don't understand why friend function also have the ability to access to all members of class. Is it the set and get method shouldn't be used in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Friend is for things that form a single unit of abstraction with the class: operators working on the class, a container and its iterator, etc.

Everything else needs to go through the public interface of the class. This may include getters and setters, though you need to think about whether they make sense. Do not mindlessly write getters and setters for every property.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another answer, be aware that providing a getter and a setter
for *every* data member is equivalent to giving up encapsulation; making
these data members public would be equivalent.
See for example this C++ core guideline:
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-get

Moreover, in C++ the `const` keyword offers the ability to write
reliable getters, setters and constructors but in other languages
it is very difficult and expensive (in source code and execution time)
to ensure that your data members won't change their state inconsistently.
See for example this very good tutorial about Java:
https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices

A good practice encouraged by Scott Meyers is to provide your class with
the *minimal* set of member functions (in order to access private members)
that makes the class ensure its invariant.
Any other higher level operation is just expressed as a *non-member*
*non-friend* function that relies on the previous set of member functions
so that it is independent from the internal details of the class and cannot
break the invariant by inadvertence.
This actually increases the encapsulation.
See for example the original (quite old!) article of Scott Meyers:
http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197 
or item 23
"Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions" of
his book "Effective C++, Third Edition" (Addison-Wesley Professional
Computing Series, 2005) 
and this C++ core guideline: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-member